difference between runtime and compile time with regard to dynamic binding
I am learning C++ and if I have classes
class Core {...}


class Grad: public Core {...}

then
Core* p;
Core& ref;

may be Grad objects which is not determined at compile time but at runtime hence the use of virtual functions to let such an object use its own method if it is overriden.
My question is: why can the compiler not find this out at compile time?
I read the most upvoted answer on SO about runtime vs compile time but it did not cover my question. Another one explains that C++ just does not do this during compilation time but I wonder why this is the case it seems easy to do a type check for inheritance hierarchies.

You can initialize p and ref with either Core or Grad based on a runtime determined condition. BTW: ref must be initialized and cannot be reassigned (unlike p).

"why can the compiler not find this out at compile time" It can in some cases, look up "devirtualization". Also there are some alternatives to virtual functions that do this at compile-time (CRTP).

It would be easier if the question included a [mcve], then we could check if it happens at compile-time or not in your case,

Imagine a function Core *fun() {int i; std::cin >> i; if (i == 0) return new Grad; else return new AnotherClassDerivedFromCore;}  and it is used to initialise p (viz.  Core *p = fun();) or to initalise ref (via Core &ref = *fun();).   In both these cases it is impossible for the compiler to know the actual type of the object pointed to be p or the one referred to by ref, since the actual type depends on data it doesn't have.    Code in other source files that sees the declarations extern Core *p; extern Core &ref may have no visibility of the types of the actual objects at all.

Is C++ virtual function always resolved in run time? and Why are virtual functions handled at runtime? and Why can't run-time polymorphism be solved at compile time?


My question is: why can the compiler not find this out at compile time?

Take this case for example:
Core core;
Grad grad;
bool b = GetFromUser(); // get boolean input from the user
Core& ref = b ? core : grad;

The compiler cannot determine at compile time if ref refers to a Core instance or a Grad instance. It will be determined at runtime based on the input from the user.
A similar example can be constructed using a pointer instead of a reference.
There could be a case where the pointer/reference is assigned to an object returned from a function which can be (1) dependant on some runtime condition or (2) not visible at all to the compiler in this translation unit.
On the other hand in some other cases it might be possible for the compiler to determine this at compile time.
Bottom line:
The compiler cannot always determine it at compile time.

oh yeah... easy... thanks!
